# How to send data-pk value from editable to server in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

How can I send the data-pk from editable to server. I have already used both params and source but it is not working. Please help me solve with this situation. I think `$('#customer_name').attr('data-pk')` is not working in `pk` but when I alert it have value, and I don't understand

```
$('#customer_name').editable({
            type: 'text',
            pk: $('#customer_name').attr('data-pk'),
            url: '{% url 'change_customer_inline' %}',
            title: 'Enter customer name',
            success: function (response, newValue) {

                if (!response) {
                    return "Unknown error!"
                }
                if (response.success === false) {
                    return respond.msg;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '{% url 'change_customer_inline' %}',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                        'customer_id': $('#customer_name').attr('data-pk'),
                    },
                    responseTime: 200,
                    response: function (settings) {
                        if (settings.data.value) {
                            this.responseText = '{"success": true}';
                        } else {
                            this.responseText = '{"success": false, "msg": "required"}';
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

view.py

```
def change_customer_inline(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        if request.is_ajax():
            customer_id = request.POST.get('customer_id')
            customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
            if request.POST.get('customer_name'):
                customer.name = request.POST.get('customer_name')
                customer.save()
    except OSError as e:
        error = messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, e, extra_tags='change_customer_inline')
        HttpResponse(error)
return render_to_response('order_list.html')
```